# How to change the default CSS of ng-multiselect-dropdown?

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I have a multi select dropdown as below-

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select name'" 
    [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"> 
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Right now it's like this-
[image]

When I'm selecting the options it's breaking the line if the option has two words. For example-
If my options are

- Adrian Wallhart
- Cillian Robertson

I don't want the words to get to the next line.

But I want it to be like this-
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're already able to change the style of the component, so what you're asking is rather how to achieve your final CSS.

Here are the steps :

- Make the dropdown container have a fixed width (it should already be done)
- Constraint the dropdown option to the width of its parent
- Tell the text of the option not to break

Here is a snippet to show you how you can do that (look the last CSS class) :

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.option {
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container.right .option {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fault">
  <div class="option">Some content that is long enough to break</div>
</div>

<div class="container right">
  <div class="option">Some content that is long enough to break</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can of course adapt the width of the container to your own liking by just removing the width of the container : the options will stretch to the longest one, provided that you remove the `overflow` properties

Answer (score 0):

The way you achieve this is by setting the styles globally. Global styles will override those of ng-multiselect. Check the DOM to see, what elements does `ng-multiselect-dropdown` create and make a style specifically targeting it. Don't use `ng-deep` since it is depricated.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yeah I wanted to get the CSS part of that right. I used width:100% but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want selected values in single line.
please check this:

[ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiselect-dropdown-918ovx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)